Moving Website to New Server, Assembly Missing
I'm moving a website from Server 2012 to Server 2022. It's build in VS2019 and builds and runs fine against a test server. It's publishes and runs fine on the old 2012 site. When I publish to the new server I get this this error.
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. Access is denied.j
I made sure that IIS has the same security permissions.
I examined web.config and all the compiler references look correct with the right version numbers.
I tried uninstalling that assembly in nuget with no effect.
The test site where I do development is a Server 2019. I'm wondering if I should build a new 2019 server to try and publish.
Any suggestions on where to look?

I found that the key error message should be this： Access is denied.? Have you ensured that the IIS_IUSRS user has sufficient permissions? Or have you set credentails for special user in IIS Application Pool Identity?

We have created an AD user to run the site because access to outside file resources are needed. (This is an intranet, so security is a bit more relaxed.) I verified that user can access all the folders in the physical path. Do you know if there are any other folders this user needs access?

Xudong, you are right!!!!!!! You got me thinking so I gave "everyone" full access and it works. Thank you so much!!!!! I was banging my head on the wrong direction.

I'm glad your problem has been solved.

Xudong Peng is right. It was permissions blocking.
